# Android Studio git cloning not showing files correctly

Tags: git, android-studio, github, intellij-idea, ide

I'm having problems using git with my project, I need to work on the same project on my two devices, but I can't seem to make it work on the device where I'm cloning my project to.

[Here's how the project structure looks in my main device, where the project and repository were created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWnqO.png)

[And here's how it looks in my secondary device, I can't run anything and it doesn't detect java files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A8P9.png)

I've tried deleting the project folder and cloning again, deleting the .idea folder and restarting (which messed up even more the structure), changing the SDK in the project manager, and nothing worked.

Edit: More things I tried: I installed Gradle and executed the commands "gradle init" and "gradle tasks --all" in the terminal, then synced the project with gradle files. Still doesn't work.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit: Found the solution**, I struggled and the solution was very stupid, I was opening the whole folder in Android Studio instead of only the project marked with the android icon.

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpMsJ.png)

The problem had a very simple solution, and I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Have you tried to run "Reload" from Gradle tool window?

Comment: @y.bedrov With your comment I realized I was missing all the gradle options, so I installed gradle, and executed the commands "gradle init" and "gradle tasks --all" and after that, I now had the options to sync and reload, I did that, and it still doesn't work. It's showing the files the same way.

Comment: Are there any errors in idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...")?

Comment: There are some errors, but I can't identify if any of them are important or related to this problem. Should I upload the log file?

Comment: Yes, if it's possible.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to find a solution to the problem, I put in the main post.